# fitting using unstable poles

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, frequency, transient

I am trying to take into account the frequency dependent behavior of R and L in an LTspice simulation. So I fit their frequency behavior using Vector fitting technique and deduce the equivalent electrical circuit that reproduces the same behavior. Then, I run my transient simulation. My question is, will the fact that some of the poles used for the fitting are unstable (have a positive real part) impact in any way my time domain simulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, will the fact that some of the poles used for the fitting are unstable (have a positive real part) impact in any way my time domain simulation?

No, it won't impact your time domain simulation.

As long as LTSpice converges to a solution, that solution is pretty numerically accurate even though the system you are modeling contains unstable poles.

Comment: Because I have tried forcing the stability of poles by inverting the sign of the real part, and I ended up having a simulation of 10^37 voltages...

Comment: @Wallflower If your circuit is only with R and L it's impossible to have RHS poles. You must have active elements in there, in which case that's where you need to look at. Saying that with a RHS pole it's stable but with that one inverted (made LHS) it's not, probably means it's the other way around, and you have a sign problem (possibly).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen You are right, I confused the signs in my comment. The idea is when I use the VF scipt to fitt the frequency behavior of Z=R(f)+jL(f)w, with stable poles (when enforced by the user, which actually inverts the sign of unstable poles if there are any), the fitting is sooo poor. I then tried to disable the stable poles flag, and I get an excellent fitting, so I started wondering, if the possibility of having unstable poles lead to the divergence of my LTspice simulation..

Comment: @Wallflower No matter what system you have, if it doesn't satisfy the Routh-Hurwitz criterion it will be unstable. What Enrico is saying is that the simulator doesn't care if it is stable or not, it will show a response. I guess what you *meant* was if the system will still be stable if a pole ends up on the RHS. No, it will not be. The rotten apple will spoil everything.